# How to implement logging in fte ant script

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

I am trying to implement logging in FTE, i need to log all the monitors information that how many monitor jobs got successfully executed and how many got failed.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help. Are you implementing your own logging?

Monitor logs are published on SYSTE.FTE/Log topic. You can subscribe to receive publications on this topic and process the way you want. More details [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/monitor_log_xsd.htm).

Comment: Thanks for reply, Is it possible to implement our own logging?

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe to "SYSTEM.FTE/#" topic and receive all publications.